# json result from url using class with variables

Tags: php, json

pool.php contains code that returns json.

```
[{"tickets":"0","users":"0","pool_range":"2016-01-24 - 2016-01-27"}]
```

pool.php basics

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$output = array_values($results);
$json = json_encode($output);
echo $json;
```

php

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $current_timestamp = date('Y-m-d') . "T" . date('H:i:s');
    $pool = new pool_data();

    var_dump($pool);

    class pool_data {
        public $users;
        public $tickets;
        public $pool_range;

        function __construct() {
            $pool_json = file_get_contents('./pool.php');
            $temp = json_decode($pool_json, true);
            $this->users = $temp["users"];
            $this->tickets = $temp["tickets"];
            $this->pool_range = $temp["pool_range"];
        }
    }
?>
```

When I var_dump $pool

```
object(pool_data)#1 (3) {
  ["users"]=>
  NULL
  ["tickets"]=>
  NULL
  ["pool_range"]=>
  NULL
}
```

allow_url_fopen is enabled

```
if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
    echo "I'm enabled";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"pool.php returns json as follows"*? How does it "return" JSON? Does is contain the exact json you posted? Or it contains code that output that json?

Comment: @axiac contains code that outputs json.

Comment: Well, what do you expect to get when you `file_get_contents('./pool.php')`? The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) explains very clear: **Reads entire file into a string**. It doesn't say anything about the file being interpreted as PHP or anything else. It just returns **the exact content of ./pool.php**, whatever that content is. `allow_url_fopen` doesn't help here because you don't use `file_get_contents()` to read a remote file identified by an URL. The file is local, its content is delivered as is.

Comment: @axiac so I did notice that in pool.php, if I used return $json it didn't work but if I echo $json it worked with what dragoste posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file returns array of objects (one element array in this example) but you're using it as associative array. You indeed passed second `json_decode` argument to `true` which decodes json to array instead of object, but still, you are missing one dimension. You can `var_dump` it, to see the exact structure after decoding.

So your class should look like this:

```
class pool_data {
    public $users;
    public $tickets;
    public $pool_range;

    function __construct() {
        $pool_json = file_get_contents('./pool.php');
        $temp = json_decode($pool_json, true);
        $this->users = $temp[0]["users"];           //added [0]
        $this->tickets = $temp[0]["tickets"];       //added [0]
        $this->pool_range = $temp[0]["pool_range"]; //added [0]
    }
}
```

I've created these two files on my local server and it works fine.
Result:

```
object(pool_data)[1]
  public 'users' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'tickets' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'pool_range' => string '2016-01-24 - 2016-01-27' (length=23)
```

You can also have issues with relative path if file containing this code has been included by for example index.php which is somewhere else.

To be sure, you can add `dirname(__DIR__)`, to make it absolute path.

Change this line:

```
        $pool_json = file_get_contents('./pool.php');
```

To this:

```
        $pool_json = file_get_contents(dirname(__DIR__) . '/pool.php');
```

This will make you sure that you're looking in the same directory that the current file is in.

Comment: Did you check `$pool_json` content? Maybe you have issues with relative path to `./pool.php` file.

Comment: Sorry, yes my issue was with the relative path.

Comment: Please see my updated answer to see how you can easily solve such issues.

Comment: @Tsukasa how does this answer solves your problem? You said `pool.php` contains PHP code.

Comment: @axiac yes it does contain php code and yes it was interrupted to the json  result.

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$output = array_values($results);
$json = json_encode($output);
echo $json;  Sorry this is my first PHP project but it did do what I needed it to.